# Regression model with missing data in dependant variable

Tags: r, regression

```
modelo <- lm( P3J_IOP~ PräOP_IOP +OPTyp + P3J_Med, data = na.omit(df))
summary(modelo)
```

Error:

> Fehler in step(modelo, direction = "backward") :
> Number of lines used has changed: remove missing values?

I have a lot of missing values in my dependent variable `P3J_IOP`.

Has anyone any idea how to create the model?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post an example of your data?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** unfortunately, this is going to be hard.

It is fairly difficult to make linear regression work smoothly with missing values in the predictors/dependent variables (this is true of *most* statistical modeling approaches,  with the exception of random forests). In case it's not clear, the problem with stepwise approaches with missing data in the predictor is:

- incomplete cases (i.e., observations with missing data for any of the current set of predictors) must be dropped in order to fit a  linear model;
- models with different predictor sets will typically have different sets of incomplete cases, leading to the models being fitted on different subsets of the data;
- models fitted to different data sets aren't easily comparable.

You basically have the following choices:

- drop any predictors with large numbers of missing values, then drop all cases that have missing values in *any* of the remaining predictors;
- use some form of *imputation*, e.g. with the `mice` package, to fill in your missing data (in order to do proper statistical inference, you need to do **multiple** imputation, which may be hard to combine with stepwise regression).

There are some advanced statistical techniques that will allow you to *simultaneously* do the imputation and the modeling, such as the `brms` package (here is [some documentation on imputation with brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_missings.html)), but it's a pretty big hammer/jump in statistical sophistication if all you want to do is fit a linear model to your data ...